# Windows 10 "Save As" dialogue takes a long time to come up

Tags: windows-10, speed, save-as

I am running Windows 10 on a Dell XPS 17 that's only a couple of months old.  Most things run blazingly fast, with one exception:  Whenever I try to save a document (either from the web or from within an program, including both Microsoft programs and programs from other vendors), it takes several seconds for the "Save As" dialogue to come up, during which I get to watch the little Windows wheel spin around and around and around.

My much older Dell Inspiron 7559 is slower in every way, but the "Save As" dialogues generally come up in the blink of an eye.  Both machines are configured pretty much identically (same directory structure, all the same software, etc.)

Does anyone have an explanation, or better yet a fix?

Comment: [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have solved this problem by deleting the contents of

c:\users[MYNAME]\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations

I'm going to leave the question up partly because I'm not yet sure this has solved all instances of the problem and partly because I'd still like to know how to stop this from happening again.